# How do I theme windows like Google Chrome, with WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, google-chrome

You know how Chrome windows are super custom looking and what not, they have a custom title bar that has custom looking minimize/maximize/close buttons. How would I do this with WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want custom windows for WPF take a look at http://www.codeplex.com/WPFWindow

Answer (score 5):

Some information available below that might set you on the right track.

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx